# Creating nested dictionary for JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, dictionary, mobile

I am trying to replicate the json format for a POST request, but I am having trouble working with the following 2D dictionary in Swift.

```
payload = {"cardholder": {
    "address": {
        "city": "city",
        "state": "MA",
        "street": "street",
        "zip_code": "11111"
    },
    "shipping_address": {
        "city": "city",
        "state": "MA",
        "street": "street",
        "zip_code": "11111"
    }
}}
```

Is there a way I can set up addressDetails and shippingDetails?

```
            var addressDetails = ["city": self.newCity!, "state": self.newState!,"street": self.newStreet!,"zip_code": self.newZipcode!]
            var shippingDetails = ["city": self.newCity!, "state": self.newState!,"street": self.newStreet!,"zip_code": self.newZipcode!]
            if self.newUnit != ""{
                addressDetails["unit"] = self.newUnit!
                shippingDetails["unit"] = self.newUnit!
            }
            
            var test: [String:[String:[String:String]]] = ["cardholder": ["address": addressDetails]]
```

Comment: When using JSON and Swift you should always try and use `Codable` with appropriate structs.  It is simpler and more reliable than trying to work with raw containers

Comment: `shipping_address` is a property of `cardholder` - You  need to add that key/value to the dictionary associated with `cardholder`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: yes. Everything you need to do is add `shippingDetails` to the `test["cardholder"]` dict:

```swift
var test: [String:[String:[String:String]]] = ["cardholder": ["address": addressDetails, "shipping_address": shippingDetails]]
```

However, I totally agree with @Paulw11, you should not fiddle around with dictionaries that way. Use structs that conform to `Codable` instead:

```swift
struct Address: Codable {
    var city: String
    var state: String
    var street: String
    var zipCode: String
    var unit: String?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case city, state, street, zipCode = "zip_code", unit
    }
}

struct Cardholder: Codable {
    var address: Address
    var shippingAddress: Address
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case address, shippingAddress = "shipping_address"
    }
}

struct Payload: Codable {
    var cardholder: Cardholder
}


...

let addressDetails = Address(city: self.newCity!, state: self.newState!, street: self.newStreet!, zipCode: self.newZipcode!, unit: self.newUnit == "" ? nil : self.newUnit)
let shippingDetails = Address(city: self.newCity!, state: self.newState!, street: self.newStreet!, zipCode: self.newZipcode!, unit: self.newUnit == "" ? nil : self.newUnit)
var test = Payload(cardholder: Cardholder(address: addressDetails, shippingAddress: shippingDetails))
```